# Different indexing and search strategies on same field without doubling index size?

Tags: solr, lucene

For a phrase search, we want to bring up results only if there's an exact match (without ignoring stopwords). If it's a non-phrase search, we are fine displaying results even if the root form of the word matches etc.

We currently pass our data through standardTokenizer, StopFilter, PorterStemFilter and LowerCaseFilter. Due to this when user wants to search for "password management", search brings up results containing "password manager".

If I remove StemFilter, then I will not be able to match for the root form of the word for non-phrase queries. I was thinking if I should index the same data as part of two fields in document.

For the first field (to be used for phrase searches), following tokenizers/filters will be used:
StandardTokenizer, LowerCaseFilter

For the second field (Non-phrase searches)
StandardTokenizer, StopFilter, PorterStemFilter, LowerCaseFilter

Now, based on whether it's a phrase search or not, I need to rewrite user's query to search in the appropriate field.

Is this the right way to address this issue? **Is there any other way to achieve this without doubling index size?**

let's say user's query is 
    `summary:"Furthermore, we should also fix this"`

Internally this will be translated to 
    `summary_field1:"Furthermore, we should also fix this"`

If user's query is 
    `summary:(Furthermore, we should also fix this)`

Internally this will be translated to 
    `+summary_field2:furthermor +summary_field2:we +summary_field2:should +summary_field2:also +summary_field2:fix`

both summary_field1 and summary_field2 index the same data. summary_field1 passes through only StandardTokenizer and LowerCaseFilter, whereas summary_field2 passes through StandardTokenizer, StopFilter, PorterStemFilter and LowerCaseFilter.

Please let me know if I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By defining two different fields you can search for exact matches.
By using boosts you can also bring results in one query. For example:

```
(firstField:"password management")^5 OR (secondField:"pasword management")^1
```

Comment: when you say two different fields, is it as in the question (same data passed through different analysis)? Why do I need to have a boolean query on both the fields instead of just deciding the field based on whether it's a phrase search or not?

Comment: Yes two different fields has the same data with different analysis. If you can control the search terms then you don't need the boolean query. But using a boolean query saves you from merging results from two different query's.

Comment: why do i need to merge results from two different queries? I will only  query on one of the fields all the time. 

Thanks

Comment: If you don't need to query two fields at a time you don't need merging.

Comment: thanks @hkn . Is there any other way to achieve this without doubling index size?

Comment: As far as I know there is no easy way to achieve this without increasing index size. But you may choose not to store contents of the both fields which will decrease index size.

Comment: When a field is stemmed, only the stemmed part is indexed. So you will get exact matches to different words that share the same root.