# Exact phrase search using lucene without increasing number of fields

Tags: full-text-search, lucene, text-analysis, exact-match

For a phrase search, we want to bring up results only if there's an exact match (without ignoring stopwords). If it's a non-phrase search, we are fine displaying results even if the root form of the word matches etc.

We currently pass our data through standardTokenizer, StopFilter, PorterStemFilter and LowerCaseFilter. Due to this when user wants to search for "password management", search brings up results containing "password manager".

If I remove StemFilter, then I will not be able to match for the root form of the word for non-phrase queries. I was thinking if I should index the same data as part of two fields in document.

I have asked same question at [Different indexing and search strategies on same field without doubling index size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292446/exact-phrase-search-using-lucene). However folks at office are not happy about indexing the same data as part of two fields. (we currently have around 20 text fields in lucene document). Is there any way to support both the cases I listed above using TokenFilters?

Say, for a StopFilter, make changes so that it emits both the input token and ? (for ignored word) with same position increments. Similarly for StemFilter, it emits both the input token and stemmed token with same position increments. Basically input and output tokens (even ignored ones) have same positions.

Is it safe to go ahead with this approach? Has anyone else faced the requirements listed here? Are there any Filters readily available which do something similar to what I mentioned in my approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what you mean by "input and output tokens." Are you storing the data twice - once as stemmed and once non-stemmed?

If you aren't storing it twice, I don't think your method will work. Suppose the stored word is `jumping` and they search for `jumped`. Your query parser can emit `jump` and `jumped` but it still won't match `jumping` unless you have a value stored as `jump`.

And if you're going to store the value once as stemmed and once as non-stemmed, then why not just store it in two fields? Then you won't have to deal with weird tokenizer changes.

Comment: @Xodarp: Yeah, plan is to store it twice without using two fields (Just to simplify things while converting app Query Language to Lucene queries). Do you have any idea if this is how search engines are implemented? Thanks

Comment: Most search engines have the opinion that storage is cheap and latency is expensive, so they do tend to go the route of storing things redundantly. Whether Google has multiple fields (or even the idea of "fields") I couldn't say.

Comment: I should add: if you make these tokenizer changes you'll have all sorts of issues with highlighting etc. Think carefully about whether it's really easier to mangle Lucene's code than it is to do the translation.